# Hiding navigation menu based on a condition after login in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created navigation menu using drawer navigation menu option and my menus are appearing now after login based on the user role which I will get from the api I want to hide certail menu.How to do that

My menu is build like this .

```
const AppStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Onboarding: {
      screen: OnboardingScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => {}
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <Drawer focused={focused} screen="Home" title="Home" />
        )
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <Drawer focused={focused} screen="OrganizationListScreen" title="Organizations" />
        )
      })
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <Drawer focused={focused} screen="ContactListScreen" title="Contact" />
        )
      })
     },


    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => {}
      }
    },
    Dashboard: {
      screen: DashboardStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <Drawer focused={focused} screen="Dashboard" title="Dashboard" />
        )
      }
    },
    Order: {
      screen: OrderStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <Drawer focused={focused} screen="ShoppingCart" title="Cart" />
        )
      }
    },
    ProductDetail: {
      screen: ProductDetailsScreen,
      navigationOptions:  {
        drawerLabel: () => {}

      }
    },
    OrgList: {
      screen: OrganizationListScreen,
      navigationOptions:  {
        drawerLabel: () => {}

      }
    },
    ContactList: {
      screen: ContactListScreen,
      navigationOptions:  {
        drawerLabel: () => {}

      }
    },
  },
  Menu
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);
export default AppContainer
```

Now is there any option so that after successful login I can get the menu collections and manipulate them to show and hide them.

Thanks 
Utpal Maity

Comment: createSwitchNavigator may help you. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

Comment: Use custom drawer navigator.

Comment: @KishanBharda any example

Comment: @Utpal I just posted answer. Please check hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First create `customDrawer` like below : 
**CustomDrawer.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

class CustomDrawer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      validUserMenu: [
        key: 'First', title: 'First', screen: 'FirstScreen',
        key: 'Login', title: 'Login', screen: 'LoginScreen',
        key: 'Home', title: 'Home', screen: 'HomeScreen'
      ],
      invalidUserMenu: [
        key: 'InvalidFirst', title: 'First', screen: 'InvalidFirst',
        key: 'InvalidSecond', title: 'Login', screen: 'InvalidSecond',
      ],
      isLogin: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    // Check here if user is login or not
    // For example from storage
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    if (user) {
      this.setState({ isLogin: true });
    }
  }

  navigateToScreen = (route) => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        {
          this.state.isLogin ? this.state.validUserMenu.map((menu) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={menu.key} onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen(menu.screen)}>
              <Text>{menu.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )) : this.state.invalidUserMenu.map((menu) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={menu.key} onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen(menu.screen)}>
              <Text>{menu.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )) 
        }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomDrawer;
```

Then your `createDrawerNavigator` :

```js
import CustomDrawer from 'CustomDrawer_path'

const AppStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  Onboarding: {screen: OnboardingScreen}
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileStack},
  Settings: {screen: SettingsStack},
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
  Dashboard: {screen: DashboardStack},
  Order: {screen: OrderStack},
  ProductDetail: {screen: ProductDetailsScreen},
  OrgList: {screen: OrganizationListScreen},
  ContactList: {screen: ContactListScreen}
}, {
  contentComponent: CustomDrawer
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);
export default AppContainer
```